# Location Not Loading

Tags: javascript, spotify

When I used the example code from this [page](https://developer.spotify.com/docs/apps/api/1.0/location.html) to get a users location it never loads.  As in the following code is never reached:

console.log('Found you!', loc.latitude, loc.longitude);

Any idea what could be causing this issue?

Answer (score 0):

The promise is rejected which runs the optional fail callback function. Try this:

```
    require(['$api/location#Location'], function(Location) {
        var loc = Location.query();
        loc.load('latitude', 'longitude').done(function() {
            console.log('Found you!', loc.latitude, loc.longitude);
        }).fail(function(loc, error) {
            console.log("I failed!", error)
        });
    });
```

I don't know why it's being rejected though.

Comment: Thanks but the latitude and longitude are undefined when it fails.

Comment: Yes, they're undefined because the location query fails.

Answer (score 0):

According to the answer on this question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20196967/1036087 the location API never actually worked and they're going to remove the documentation on it.