# What method(s) can I use for geolocation through a Spotify app?

Tags: geolocation, spotify

The Spotify Apps API doesn't allow HTML5 geolocation and apparently the documented Location api call doesn't work and is being removed from the documentation. What are some methods that I can use to geolocate a user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Solutions for finding website visitor's geolocation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11367264/solutions-for-finding-website-visitors-geolocation)  and its suggestion of http://freegeoip.net/ seems like your best option here.  You'd just have to add http://freegeoip.net/ to your manifest for access from your app.